Passing output variable to a template in the same job in Azure devops
I'm trying to pass a variable that is output in a template consisting of steps to another steps template in the same job the setup looks like this,
Error:
The semVersion parameter value is not a valid value
jobs:
     - job: job_git_tag
       displayName: Tag new version

       steps:
         - template: /templates/git/semantic_version_type.yaml
           parameters:
             semVersion: ${{ parameters.semVersion }}
         
         - template: /templates/git/git_tag.yaml
           parameters:
             module: ${{ parameters.module }}
             semVersion: $(Type.Semversion)

Template Semantic Version
parameters:
  - name: semVersion
    type: string
    default: auto
    values:
      - major
      - minor
      - patch
      - auto

steps:
  - ${{ if eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest') }}:
    - bash: |
           ### do some scripting magic and output variable
           echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=semVersion;isOutput=true]major"
    displayName: Get semantic version type
    name: Type

Git Tag Template
parameters:
  - name: module
    type: string
  - name: semVersion
    type: string
    default: patch
    values:
      - major
      - minor
      - patch

steps:

  - bash: |
      ### here the repository is checkedout and tagged with the correction version after being bumped.
    displayName: Tag new version


What is supposed to be the problem? Is there any error? Is the variable empty? ...

@RuiJarimba added the error to the description.

Can you please add the pipeline parameters definition in the first block (job: job_git_tag)?

The output variable semVersion will only be set when Build.Reason==PullRequest. What is supposed to be the behaviour when the pipeline is NOT running as part of a pull request?

You're setting a list of allowed values for the parameter semVersion in the templates:
parameters:
  - name: semVersion
    type: string
    default: auto
    values:
      - major
      - minor
      - patch
      - auto

But the pipeline will fail with the following error because $(Type.semVersion) will be created at runtime, i.e. it does not exist when compiling the pipeline:

Encountered error(s) while parsing pipeline YAML:
/pipelines/test01-pipeline.yaml (Line: 29, Col: 23): The 'semVersion' parameter value '$(Type.semVersion)' is not a valid value.

As a workaround you can remove the list of allowed values:
parameters:
  - name: semVersion
    type: string
    default: auto

Or, as an alternative, add $(Type.semVersion) to the list:
parameters:
  - name: semVersion
    type: string
    default: auto
    values:
      - major
      - minor
      - patch
      - auto
      - $(Type.semVersion)


parameters are evaluated at compile time before the pipeline run, it's not supported to pass the variables value from 1st template as the parameter of the 2nd template.
As an alternative, you can remove semVersion: $(Type.Semversion) for the 2nd template, directly invoke it in the template.
jobs:
- job: job_git_tag
  displayName: Tag new version

  steps:
    - template: /templates/git/semantic_version_type.yaml
      parameters:
        semVersion: ${{ parameters.semVersion }}
    
    - template: /templates/git/git_tag.yaml
      parameters:
        module: ${{ parameters.module }}

And 2nd template:
parameters:
  - name: module
    type: string
  # - name: semVersion
  #   type: string
  #   default: patch
  #   values:
  #     - major
  #     - minor
  #     - patch

steps:

  - bash: |
      echo $(Type.Semversion)
    displayName: Tag new version

Output on my side:

